# Создать несколько потоков в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

В Qt есть аналогичный способ создания нескольких потоков?

```
for (int i = 0; i < iThreadCount; ++i) {
    threads.push_back(boost::thread(func));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

В Qt есть [QThreadPool](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html) и [QtConcurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html).

Например `QtConcurrent::map`:

```
struct Task {
  int i;
}

int foo(const Task& t) {
  return t.i * t.i;
}

QVector<Task> tasks;
tasks << Task{2} << Task{4};
QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::map(tasks, foo);
future.waitForFinished();
```

Результаты выполнения `foo()` в `future.results()`.

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ кодом или более развёрнутым ответом. Сейчас ваш ответ выглядит, как комментарий

Answer (score 3):

1) [Пул потоков](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html):

```
class Thread : public QRunnable{
    void run(){
        func();
    }
};

//...
for (int i = 0; i < iThreadCount; ++i) {
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(new Thread);
}
```

2) [QtConcurrent::run](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run)

```
//вместо void тип возвращаемого значения func
QVector<QFuture<void> > futures; 

for (int i = 0; i < iThreadCount; ++i) {
    futures.append(QtConcurrent::run(func));
}
```